# Root element is missing when running entity framework migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

For some reason the migrations history table got wiped from our test database.

To fix this I restored the table from a previous backup. However there wee a few migrations missed. To apply these I commented out all the up() method code. And ran them (the idea being to in comment after I'd ran to update the history table)

However I get the error

> System.xml.xmlexception root element is missing

Any ideas? Obviously the up method is empty in this case.

Comment: Ten upvotes? How? The description isn't nearly sufficient to reproduce this. A [mcve] is required.

Comment: @GertArnold You need to take the age of the question into consideration, over 3.5 years it is not uncommon for low-quality questions to get some upvotes (likely from people who have the same problem).